# Making and error view with dynamic content in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm finishing my first web based app using Laravel 4 and it's almost done, the issue I have is the following:

I'm trying to make custom 404 error view with dynamic content, I have a form with a couple of selects populated from a DB, I do this thru the Base controller like this:

```
protected function setupLayout() {
    if (!is_null($this->layout)) {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }

    View::composer('templates.partials.footer', function ($view) {
        $languages = array('' => 'Choose Language Pair:') + Language::orderBy('order')->lists('name', 'id');
        $view->with('languages', $languages);
    });
}
```

This form needs to be present in the entire web and it works fine in all the views but the error one, when I enter an unvalid url an php error shows telling me that the variable $languages in the footer view is undefined. I tried taking out the footer from the default template and it works wonderful.

Here is how I'm handling my errors:
-in the global.php

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code) {
    //Log::error($exception);
    return BaseController::handleError($code);
});
```

-and the method in the BaseController:

```
protected function handleError($code) {
    //return View::make('404' . $code);

    switch ($code) {
        case 403:
            return Response::view('404', array(), 403);
        case 404:
            return Response::view('404', array(), 404);
        case 500:
            return Response::view('404', array(), 500);
        default:
            return Response::view('404', array(), $code);
    }
}
```

As you can see I've tried using Response::view but it seems that it doesn't load the View::composer that sends the data to the form, and the other way around using return View::make isn't good either because I need it to be an error for SEO reasons.

So...

Is there a way to send my dynamic data to my error view while getting the errors in the browser?

Thanks before hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your controllers would not load during a 404 error meaning your BaseController would never be hit.

I'd suggest placing your view composers logic in your basecontroller into `app/start/global.php` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I tried that, copying the View::composer(...)... code in the global.php file inside App:error... and didn't work either...

Am I doing right what you suggested me?

Comment: Try adding it outside of `App::error()`.  If it was in there, it would never get loaded in the event there wasn't an exception happening.